# Clarification on .net core message as result of dotnet run command

Tags: c#, .net, output, .net-core

I just installed `.net core` on my MacBook and I can run the demo app fine, but when I run it I get this message in the console:

> Project trials (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing.

I am a little confused as to what this means - because to me it would make more sense if something **didn't** compile because something (in this case outputs) are missing.

**Question 1:** What are the outputs it is referring to? - Do I need to return something specific?

**Question 2:** Can someone please explain what I am misunderstanding about the statement in the quote above?

Comment: Isn't it trying to say that if "trials" is to be run it needs to be compiled because the outputs (e.g. trials.exe) aren't there? Otherwise it could skip compilation IF the ouputs are up to date with respect to the inputs.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - yes that makes sense. Once I made a change, it just updated the app. Then I saw that the files where created after that message.

Answer (score 0):

You should usually run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` before actually executing the project via `dotnet run`. Try that, and the message should be suppressed then.

Comment: actually "dotnet run" not only executing: it compiles source code, generates an output program and then runs that program

Comment: @Set, that's correct, but it would be much cleaner to explicitly do a build (in CI system for example).